# Correct order for electronic ballast and circuit breaker

Tags: electricity

I´m setting up a circuit which involves a light, an electronic ballast and a circuit breaker in order to protect the whole connection (Very usual power failures).

- Is the circuit breaker recommendable?
- If so, which is the correct order for the set up?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `correct order for the setup`?

Comment: Should i connect the light to the ballast and it to the circuit breaker? Or the light to the circuit breaker and then the ballast?

Comment: think about what you are asking .... what is the purpose of a circuit breaker? .... is it meant to protect only against lamp failure?

Comment: To protect from power failures. In my zone it is very usual to have those continued by power surges. I want to protect the ballast since it costs around 75 USD here and a circuit breaker just 10 USD.

Comment: that is what I am talking about .... think a little before asking .... you answered your own question about the order of setup

Comment: you probably need a surge protector instead of a breaker